# Непереведённые надписи в интерфейсе редактирования тегов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице с [вопросами по тегу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jhm) вижу такое:

[image: The *** tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?]

На странице [с описанием тега](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/jhm/info) такое:

[image: There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet! Usage guidance, also known as a tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.]

Кстати, если в урле заменить тег на [несуществующий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/foobar/info), тоже видна английская надпись:

[image: We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.]

Нажмём [«создать описание к тегу»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/5019), видим:

[image: Editing tag info]

Тут и Editing tag info, и Usage guidance (excerpt), и справа портянка про The usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt...

Если к тегу [уже есть описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info), то там внизу кнопочка Edit Tag Info:

[image: Edit Tag Info]

Comment: Про страницу метки и кнопку edit tag info, также: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1082/181472

Comment: Определение краткого описания метки: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1113/181472

Comment: Страница ошибки 404: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/249/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ой, извините. Буду искать в следующий раз :-)

Comment: да ничего страшного, у вас тут есть и ранее неотмеченные баги. Я просто связываю вопросы для порядка. Во втором и третьем висят варианты перевода, ждут чтобы за них проголосовали. ;)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, проголосовал :-)